# change html font size by a button

Tags: html, ios

hi guys i wrote a simple app that displays an html file in a webview ,the html file is in the main bundle.
i was wondering how can i make the html file font-size bigger/smaller by a two buttons
this is my .m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize webView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"jama" ofType:@"htm"]isDirectory:NO]]];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)increase:(id)sender {

    }

- (IBAction)decrease:(id)sender {

    }


@end
```

and this is my html file which is in my main bundle

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="Generator" content="Cocoa HTML Writer">
  <meta name="CocoaVersion" content="1265.21">
  <style type="text/css">
    p.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; text-align: left; font: 21.0px 'Geeza Pro'}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<p dir="rtl" class="p1"><b> hello </b></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[UIWebview](http://www.w3schools.com/js/) has a method that can execute JavaScript command inside the DOM of the current site using `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`.

**With the following method call a simple JavaScript command such as:**

```
// your javascript command that will alter the layout og your html 
NSString *javascript = @"document.getElementById('myP').style.fontSize='large';";

// tell the webview to execute a script on your current page. this method must be called once the page has completely loaded.  
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascript];
```

Note: you need to know basic [JavaScript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/) and HTML to understand how the command works as your interacting with with web content.

Comment: maybe because i'm new to programming i didn't understand, can you simplify the answer please